# Modify address fields of stored mail messages

Tags: c#, ews-managed-api

We migrated from on-premise Exchange to Exchange Online with Bit-Titan. Later we discovered that From/To fields of internal users that don't exists anymore are displayed with a wrong user. Lets say an email was sent by user A, Outlook is showing now user B as sender. The original user (A) is still present in the internet header `To` field. So we can identify which elements are affected and how.

But I was not able to modify the address fields of mail messages in a mailbox or public folder.

I tried so far:

- EWS managed api `item.From = new EmailAddress("Name", "email@domain.com");       item.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve, true);`
  Returns ServiceResponseException "Message is not draft."

How would that be possible?

- Using `ExportItems`, edititing the exportet data, and reimporting with `UploadItem`?
- Using `Extended MAPI`?
- Using `Outlook Redemption`?

Comment: not sure to fully understand the question. you want to update existing sent emails in recipients mailboxes?

Comment: Yes this is correct, as these e-mails have been assigned a wrong contact when we migrated with bittian. We are looking for a way to correct that.

Comment: i see. will check in our code then.

Comment: i think what you try to achieve is not possible. The error message comes back from exchange directly. The object you try to update is not a draft anymore then it is immutable. Which I think is a correct behavior.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/1062d686-dd24-445b-8b60-e1b2c3bc94dd/modify-sender-or-from-address-of-emailmessage-using-ews-api?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment maybe with the ExtendedProperties like mentionned in this thread. But I doubt.

Comment: Thank you for your effort! The link to the extended properties look promising.

Comment: let me know. I am curious and I cannot really play with it at the moment